# TimerTask returning nullpointer Exception

Tags: java, timertask

I have piece of code which runs every 5 seconds in TimerTask, Also using ExecutorService to span a thread for each pool.

```
if(!alertingPools.isEmpty())
{
    Object[] Pools = alertingPools.values().toArray();
    executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool((Pools.length));
    for (Object pool : Pools) {
        executorService.execute(new DataAccumulation(timeStartSecData,
            timeEndSec,pool, jsonArrayResult));

finally {
    executorService.shutdown();
}
```

But getting following null pointer exception sometimes: Not sure  why.Also using ExecutorService to span a thread for each pool

```
  Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.ebay.lbmongoservice.AlertsData$1.run(AlertsData.java:117)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
```

Comment: Wait... Why are you not using a `ScheduledExecutorService`?

Comment: I have shutdown() on line 117                                      finally {
     executorService.shutdown();
    }

Comment: @fge: How to use ScheduledExecutorService? never used it

Comment: You can `.scheduleAtFixedRate()` anything of your choice. [Link to Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). It is much easier to use than a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell if you have a `try` before the `if`, but you can't use `finally` without at least a `try`. It might not go to the `if` if the `alertingPools.isEmpty()`, which means 
it never even initializes the `executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool((Pools.length));`. This would result in the finally clause coming back as `null.shutdown` causing problems. If possible, try to move the initialization before the `if`. I would start by trying to find out weather the `alertingPools.isEmpty()` or not.